# Swift: HowTo get the difference between two struct-arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, filter

I have two custom struct-arrays...

```
struct CarStruct {
    var name : String?
    var speed : Int?
}

var allCarsArr = [CarStruct]() // should contain a lot of CarStructs
var newCarsArr = [CarStruct]() // contains only a few
```

I want to add the `newCarsArr` to `allCarsArr`.

But before that I need to prove that `newCarsArr` does not contain structs which are already in `allCarsArr`.

So how can I get all the `structs` out of `newCarsArr` which are not in `allCarsArr`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the `Equatable` protocol as an extension to your class. This is an excellent article explaining it:

[Every Value Type Should Be Equatable](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/07/01/every-swift-value-type-should-be-equatable/)

Then you can add both arrays to a Set and it will naturally exclude duplicates. You also need to adhere to `Hashable` in order to put the value in a Set but there's a simple trick of converting the value to a string and getting the `hashValue` of that.

```
struct CarStruct {
  var name : String?
  var speed : Int?
}

extension CarStruct: Hashable, Equatable {
  // For Hashable
  var hashValue:Int { return "\(self.name),\(self.speed)".hashValue }
}

// For Equatable
func ==(lhs:CarStruct, rhs:CarStruct) -> Bool {
  return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.speed == rhs.speed
}

var allCarsArr = [CarStruct]() // should contain a lot of CarStructs
let newCarsArr = [CarStruct]() // contains only a few

allCarsArr = Array(Set<CarStruct>(allCarsArr).union(newCarsArr))
```

Comment: Types also need to conform to `Hashable` to be allowed as members to a `Set` (or keys in a `Dictionary`). (Conformance to `Hashable` itself requires conformance to `Equatable`).

Comment: Yep, I was just working up an example to post when I remembered that myself. Thanks!

Comment: Note that by just using the `.hashValue` property of the simple `String` representation of the properties in the struct, the hash values might not have a very good distribution, increasing the risk of hash collisions. It would probably be advisable to use e.g. the DJB hash function, [as described in the answer to this Q&A](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111545/implementing-the-hashable-protocol-in-swift-with-the-djb-hash-function/111573#111573).

Comment: Good call, I went for simple here but a more thought-out hash algorithm is a definite improvement.

Comment: Thanks so much guys! Works fine, but however, since you're building a new array on the fly, I really need to know which  `structs` in `newCarsArr` are not in `allCarsArr`. I think `Array(Set<CarStruct>(newCarsArr).subtract(allCarsArr))` does the job?

Comment: You can use the `subtract` method to remove items in common: `Set(newCarsArr).subtract(allCarsArr)` That will give you just the new items in `newCarsArr`

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to working with sets (conforming `CarStruct` to `Hashable`), you could settle for conformance to `Equatable` and simply check the `allCarsArr` for duplicates of each car to be added from `newCarsArr`.

```
/* (example of) conformance to Equatable */
func == (lhs: CarStruct, rhs: CarStruct) -> Bool {
    return lhsName == rhsName && lhsSpeed == rhsSpeed
}

struct CarStruct : Equatable {
    var name : String?
    var speed : Int?
}

var allCarsArr = [CarStruct]()
var newCarsArr = [CarStruct]()

allCarsArr.append(CarStruct(name: "Volvo", speed: 42))
allCarsArr.append(CarStruct(name: "BMW", speed: 50))
newCarsArr.append(CarStruct(name: "BMW", speed: 80))
newCarsArr.append(CarStruct(name: "BMW", speed: 50)) // <-- duplicate

/* Add only cars from newCarsArr to allCarsArr if they don't 
   exist, priorly, in the latter */
newCarsArr.forEach { allCarsArr.contains($0) ? () : allCarsArr.append($0) }
```

If you work with large arrays, however, a better option for uniqueness is probably to use conformance to `Hashable` and working with a set or dictionary (as the above will, if `allCarsArr` grows very large, possibly yield an unwanted overhead), as is described [in Kenneth Bruno:s solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36248204/4573247).